# NDB key property to reference an attribute

Tags: python, google-app-engine

i have 3 model :

```
class admin(ndb.Model):
name = ndb.StringProperty()

class user(ndb.Model):
name = ndb.StringProperty()


class Message(ndb.Model):
sender = ndb.KeyProperty(kind="????")
receiver =  ndb.KeyProperty(kind="????")
```

and i want to reference the admin and user in my message model  , but sender and receiver  changed, it can be admin or user. i dont know what put in KeyProperty(kind=" ") .
i hope that  my question is clear

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`kind` is an optional argument. If you don't want to require that all keys are of the same kind, simply don't specify it.